# Regular expression allow up to 2 decimal places optional leading 0

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression

```
/^\d*[0-9](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

How can I modify it so that it will allow numbers like .12 and .0?  I want to keep it so they can only enter numeric values, but I need to allow values as seen above with no leading digits.

At the moment it works well but only if you provide a leading zero.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation:

```
/^(?:\d*[0-9](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|\.[0-9]{1,2})$/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!^$)\d*[0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lE9oV4/1

Comment: This will allow empty input also.

Comment: @anubhava now it wont

Answer (score 2):

Here this regexp:

```
/
^      # The string start with...
\s*    # Any leading spaces
0*     # Any leading zeros 

# Now the number we want to match
(      
   [0-9]?     # Maybe a positive number 
   # An optional decimal part
   (?:          
      [.,]       # A decimal point or a comma
      [0-9]{1,2} # One or two values after the comma
   )?
)
0*     # Perhaps some trailing zeros
/gmx
```

Demo : http://regex101.com/r/cI8xP4/1